# how to compile cuda kernel without optimizing at all?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

If i compile this

```
__global__ void dummy_kernel(float *a, int N, float* b, int N2){
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    unsigned int j = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; 
}
```

i get this empty ptx code

```
.entry _Z9dummy_kernelPfiS_i(
.param .u64 _Z9dummy_kernelPfiS_i_param_0,
.param .u32 _Z9dummy_kernelPfiS_i_param_1,
.param .u64 _Z9dummy_kernelPfiS_i_param_2,
.param .u32 _Z9dummy_kernelPfiS_i_param_3
)
{

ret; 
}
```

Is there a way to force the compiler to generate ptx without optimizing at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try -g -G switches 
And see what it puts out
I'm not sure that will cover all possible optimizations