# How should I interpret this CUDA error?

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I am teaching myself CUDA with pyCUDA. In this exercise, I want to send over a simply array of 1024 floats to the GPU and store it in shared memory. As I specify below in my arguments, I run this kernel on just a single block with 1024 threads.

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import pycuda.autoinit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arrayOfFloats = np.float64(np.random.sample(1024))
mod = SourceModule("""
  __global__ void myVeryFirstKernel(float* arrayOfFloats) {
    extern __shared__ float sharedData[];

    // Copy data to shared memory.
    sharedData[threadIdx.x] = arrayOfFloats[threadIdx.x];
  }
""")
func = mod.get_function('myVeryFirstKernel')
func(cuda.InOut(arrayOfFloats), block=(1024, 1, 1), grid=(1, 1))
print str(arrayOfFloats)
```

Strangely, I am getting this error.

```
[dfaux@harbinger CUDA_tutorials]$ python sharedMemoryExercise.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sharedMemoryExercise.py", line 17, in <module>
    func(cuda.InOut(arrayOfFloats), block=(1024, 1, 1), grid=(1, 1))
  File "/software/linux/x86_64/epd-7.3-1-pycuda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycuda-2012.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pycuda/driver.py", line 377, in function_call
    Context.synchronize()
pycuda._driver.LaunchError: cuCtxSynchronize failed: launch failed
PyCUDA WARNING: a clean-up operation failed (dead context maybe?)
cuMemFree failed: launch failed
PyCUDA WARNING: a clean-up operation failed (dead context maybe?)
cuModuleUnload failed: launch failed
```

I have tried to debug this error by changing the type of elements I am sending to my GPU (instead of float64, I use float32 for instance). I have also tried altering my block and grid sizes to no avail.

What could be wrong? What is a dead context? Any advice or ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem i see with your code is that you use `extern __shared__ ..` which means that you need to submit the size of the shared memory when you launch the kernel.

In pycuda this is done by:
`func(cuda.InOut(arrayOfFloats), block=(1024, 1, 1), grid=(1, 1),shared=smem_size)`
where smem_size is the size of the shared memory in bytes.

In your case smem_size = 1024*sizeof(float).

Comment: Another problem I see is that the kernel is not returning any results, so the compiler may optimize the kernel to be empty.  See here for a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883377/how-to-compile-cuda-kernel-without-optimizing-at-all

Comment: Thank you! @brano 's suggestion of setting the shared memory size did the trick! Thanks to Brandon too. What do you think I should return in this case to have results sent back to the CPU?

Comment: @David Pass in a second array of floats, perform a small computation (like doubling) on your first array after having loaded them into shared memory, and store the result in the second array.  Then check the results on the CPU to verify that everything worked properly.